# Is this an alternate characterization of $\lambda$-rings? Or, what is like a $\lambda$-ring but for symmetric rather than exterior powers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, exterior-algebra, symmetric-polynomials, lambda-rings

This is a question about [$\lambda$-rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9B-ring).  A $\lambda$-ring is a commutative ring together with operations $\lambda^n$ for each whole number $n$ which are analogous to the $n$th exterior power and satisfy the same identities.  There's the identity $$\lambda^n(x+y)=\sum_{i+j=n}\lambda^i(x)\lambda^j(y)$$ as well as more complicated identities for $\lambda^n(xy)$ and $\lambda^m(\lambda^n(x))$.

My question is: What if instead of exterior powers, we used symmetric ones?  As in, we could define an "$s$-ring" to be a ring together with operations $s^n$ satisfying identities analogous to the identities defining a $\lambda$-ring, but for symmetric powers instead of exterior powers.  For addition we get
$$s^n(x+y)=\sum_{i+j=n}s^i(x)s^j(y),$$
which is the same as before, but the multiplication and iteration identities are different; for instance, instead of
$$\lambda^2(xy) = \lambda^1(x)^2 \lambda^2(y) + \lambda^2(x) \lambda^1(y)^2 - 2 \lambda^2(x)\lambda^2(y)$$
and $$ \lambda^2(\lambda^2(x))=\lambda^1(x)\lambda^3(x)-\lambda^4(x)$$
we get $$s^2(xy) = s^1(x)^2 s^1(y)^2 - s^1(x)^2 s^2(y) - s^2(x) s^1(y)^2 + 2 s^2(x)s^2(y)$$
and $$ s^2(s^2(x))=s^2(x)^2 - s^1(x)s^3(x) + s^4(x).$$

(Those are the right analogues, right?  I just got those by, in the definitions of $P_k$ and $P_{k,j}$, replacing sets with multisets, and elementary symmetric polynomials with complete homogeneous ones.  I didn't actually think about symmetric powers, I just assume that it should work the same.)

My suspicion, based on what I've read, is that this should just be an alternate characterization of a $\lambda$-ring, that it should be possible to express the $s^n$ in terms of the $\lambda^n$ and vice versa.  But I don't really know this subject; I'm asking this because I kind of just stumbled across something that might be one of these "$s$-rings".

So: Is this an alternate characterization of a $\lambda$-ring?  (If so, could you provide a reference?)  And if not, is it a known sort of thing, and where would I read about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I now have most of an answer, which I will post here.  That said... any references would really be appreciated.  I am still looking for references on the matter; I don't want to have to rederive this theory myself.

Anyway, yes, it seems to be an alternate characterization of a $\lambda$-ring, via the usual way of converting between $e_n$ (elementary symmetric polynomials) and $h_n$ (complete homogeneous polynomials), i.e., the relation $\sum_{i=0}^k (-1)^i e_i h_{k-i}=0$, or, in this context, $\sum_{i=0}^k (-1)^i \lambda^i(x) s^{k-i}(x)=0$.

Edit: You could also do the simpler $s^i(x)=(-1)^i \lambda^i(-x)$; this is equivalent by Vandermonde.

I don't *quite* have this proved, but if I make the probably-true assumption that when verifying these identities in the ring of symmetric functions, or the ring of symmetric functions in two types of variables, that I only need to check elements whose coefficients are nonnegative, then I can prove it.  Short version is, ring of symmetric functions is the free $\lambda$-ring on one generator, ring of symmetric functions is the free $\lambda$-ring on two generators (I don't have a reference for that but it seems to follow from the fact that ring of symmetric functions is the free $\lambda$-ring on one generator together with the fact that the elementary symmetric polynomials in two types of variables generate as a ring the ring of symmetric functions in two types of variables), so if it works there it works anywhere.  And of course it works there, because that's how the identities are defined (at least, as I said, for the elements without negative coefficients; I am having some trouble handling those).

So I'm not going to accept this answer, because I'm not considering this closed; I'm still looking for a reference so I don't have to rederive the whole theory myself. Thanks all!

Edit: OK, here's a reference that works -- it doesn't explicitly state everything, as such, but it essentially says it.  It calls the operations $S^i$, so I guess that's the notation to use.  http://lipn.univ-paris13.fr/~duchamp/Books&more/Lascoux/Cbms.pdf  I'll accept this answer once the system lets me (unless someone has a better one!); meanwhile I have another, less trivial, question about $\lambda$-rings which I'll ask on MathOverflow soon probably...

Edit: OK, over in chat, Darij Grinberg posted a better reference -- if he wants to post it as a separate answer I'll upvote it, though I can't accept it! -- which is Hazewinkel, Gubareni, and Kirichenko's book "Algebras, Rings, and Modules", volume 3; it discusses lambda rings in a way that puts the $\lambda^i$ and $\sigma^i$ (their terminology) on equal footing.  It doesn't explicitly write out the identities as I'd like, but taking a quick look I'm pretty sure they're easily derivable from what they do write.  Hooray!  This is probably as good as it's going to get.

Comment: What exactly are you seeking a proof for? As you have realized yourself, you can define "$s$-operations" $s_i : A \to A$ for every $\lambda$-ring $A$ by setting $s^i\left(x\right) = \left(-1\right)^i \lambda^i\left(-x\right)$ (or the sum formula). As you have also observed, you can rewrite the additive axiom $\lambda^k\left(x+y\right) = \sum_{i=0}^k \lambda^i\left(x\right) \lambda^{k-i}\left(y\right)$ of a $\lambda$-ring in terms of the $s$-operations, and it turns into precisely the same axiom (this should be clear from $s^i\left(x\right) = \left(-1\right)^i\lambda^i\left(-x\right)$). You ...

Comment: ... can also rewrite the multiplicative axiom of a $\lambda$-ring in terms of the $s$-operations, but the result will be as inexplicit as the original multiplicative axiom, and will not be the same (since the omega automorphism of the ring of symmetric functions does not preserve the internal product). The same holds for the $\lambda^i\left(\lambda^j\left(x\right)\right)$ axiom.

Comment: That, in general, the $s$ operations defined this way satisfy the "correct" multiplication and iteration identities, which are defined by taking the usual definitions of $P_k$ and $P_{k,j}$ (or at least the ones I know) and everywhere replacing sets by multisets.

Comment: I should probably say more -- the reason I say I can prove it so long as I don't have to worry about negatives is that, in the ring of symmetric functions (in one type of variable or in two), as long as all coefficients are positive, $\lambda^i$ and $s^i$ correspond to combinatorial operations I understand and so it is not hard to prove things about them.  Once you throw in negatives I get confused.  I can still write down what they describe but it's no longer clear why the identities should work.

Comment: What do you mean by "replacing sets by multisets"? I don't recall combinatorial formulas for the $P_k $ and $P_{i,j} $ involving sets (or even any combinatorial formulas for them).

Comment: I'm using the formulas from... well, from your book, actually!  So I'll refer to that to make explicit what I mean.  In the definition of $P_k$, on the left-hand size, instead of having $S$ be a subset of $\{1,\ldots,m\}\times\{1,\ldots,n\}$ of size $k$, instead have it be a multiset.  In the definition of $P_{k,j}$, replace $\mathcal{P}_j(H)$ by the set of multisubsets of $H$ of size $j$, and again allow $S$ to be a multiset rather than a set. In both cases, on the right-hand side, replace the elementary symmetric polynomials by complete homogeneous ones.

Comment: Ah, the formulas in terms of the alphabets (as Lascoux would probably call them)! Sorry, I didn't realize that you meant them, as I don't really count them as explicit (but I was misreading you, since you never said "explicit"). Hmm, I am not sure if I have a good reference. Have you seen Yau's "lambda-rings" book? (I don't have it with me, so I don't know what is in there, but I wouldn't be surprised if this is.)

Comment: Yeah, they're not very explicit, but I don't think that's a problem right now; the point is just that they're the appropriate analogues.  I'll go look up Yau's book, thanks!  If I'm lucky, it'll contain an answer to my other questions, too...

Comment: Why are the symmetric functions in two types of indeterminates the free $\lambda $-ring on two generators? I would derive this from the analogous property of the standard symmetric functions (in one set of indeterminates) and from the universal property of the tensor product of two $\lambda $-rings (which, as far as I can tell, is fairly straightforward to prove). I'm afraid I don't know a reference.

Comment: You know I thought I had a proof but now that I rethink it I realize I might have failed to account for some things.  But if you have at least a reference for the tensor stuff that would be helpful, I'm trying to avoid redeveloping as much of this as I can.  Meanwhile good to at least know it's true!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38940/discussion-between-harry-altman-and-darij-grinberg).

Comment: The universal property of the tensor product of two $\lambda$-rings is now in Exercise 6.11 of my lambda-rings notes ( https://sites.google.com/site/darijgrinberg/lambda ). I have stated as much of it as I could for non-special $\lambda$-rings (which you probably call pre-$\lambda$-rings); that said, it seems that special $\lambda$-rings are its natural habitat. Sorry for the overformalized ugliness that is its solution; I had to be really detailed to ensure that no extra assumptions crept in.

Comment: Oh, wow, I only just saw all those chat messages, I assumed it would notify me on math.SE, apparently not... (I've never used chat here before).  Thanks a whole bunch!